# Django both filtered and total number of a certain field

Tags: django, django-models

I have such model and query

```
class Employer(Models.model)
    name = ...

class JobTitle(Models.model)
    name = ...
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
```

and query is

```
Employer.objects.select_related('jobtitle')
                      .filter(jtt__activatedate__range=[startdate,enddate])
                      .annotate(jtt_count=Count('jobtitle'))
                      .order_by('-jtt_count')[:5]
```

As you see it returns 5 employer list which has maximum number of jobtitles which are related to that employer and whose activation date is in some certain range.

However, I also want to get the total number of jobtitles of each employer in that query.
Of course I may loop over each employer and make such query `JobTitle.objects.filter(employer = emp)` and taking length of that query but it is bad solution.

How can I achive this in that query?
Although it may not be possible to get both total number and filtered number of job titles, I may get the jobttiles of each emplyoer such that `len(emp.jobtitle)` however it also didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) lookup. So, in your case it may be like this:

```
.extra(
    select={
        'jobtitle_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOURAPP_jobtitle WHERE YOURAPP_jobtitle.employer_id = YOURAPP_employer.id'
    },
)
```

Comment: Thanks that will definetly work but does it work efficiently?

Comment: I think yes, it do, because django will execute only 1 query, the only difference is that it will be not only `select field1, field2 ...` but also the inline query: `select field1, field2, (select count(*) ...), ...`